# Finding the antiderivative of the product of two functions given only their derivative properties

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

let $\alpha'(x)=\beta(x), \beta'(x)=\alpha(x)$ and assume that $\alpha^2 - \beta^2 = 1$. how would I go about calculating the following anti derivative : $\int (\alpha (x))^5 (\beta(x))^4$d$x$.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2):

$$\alpha''(x)=\beta'(x)=\alpha(x)$$
The general solution of the ODE : $\quad\alpha''(x)=\alpha(x)\quad$ is :
 $$\quad\alpha(x)=c_1\cosh(x)+c_2\sinh(x)$$
And then : 
$$\quad\beta(x)=\alpha'(x)=c_1\sinh(x)+c_2\cosh(x)$$
This, combined with $\quad \alpha^2-\beta^2=1\quad$ implies :
$\begin{cases}
\alpha(x)=\cosh(x) \\
\beta(x)=\sinh(x) \\
\end{cases}$

$$\int \alpha^5\beta^4 dx=\int \cosh^5\sinh^4 dx=\int \left(1+\sinh^2(x) \right)^2\sinh^4(x) \cosh(x)dx$$
Continue with change of variable $\sinh(x)=t$